# Objective - C unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error:

```
'-[ProductionCellData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14dca5d0'
```

on this line of code:

```
NSString *productionItem = [[myArray objectAtIndex:keyCounter] objectForKey:@"baseLineStart"];
```

keyCounter is equal to 0 and here is what myArray looks like

[image]

I am trying to get the value of baseLineStart but I keep getting the error above....how do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like `ProductionCellData` is a custom class rather than a `NSDictionary` and `baseLineStart` is a property.

Answer (score 2):

`objectForKey` is normally used in dictionaries.

If you want to access the property, just refer to it:

```
NSString *productionItem = [myArray objectAtIndex:keyCounter].baseLineStart;
```

Or with even more modern syntax:

```
NSString *productionItem = myArray[keyCounter].baseLineStart;
```

Comment: you're code gives me an error `Property 'baseLineStart' not found on object of type 'id'`

Comment: You have to cast it, e.g. `NSString *string = ((ProductionCellData *)myArray[keyCounter]).productionItem;`

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that ProductionCellData does note responds to this selector, you should use

```
- (nullable id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

or get property from object in this way (if it is public )

```
NSString *productionItem = [[myArray objectAtIndex:keyCounter] baseLineStart];
```

Comment: Your code gives me this error `No known instance method for selector 'baseLineStart'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to find error by the following way.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [myArray objectAtIndex:keyCounter];
NSLog(@"dic:%@",dic);
NSString *productionItem = [dic objectForKey:@"baseLineStart"];

//1. observe the dic object has "baseLineStart" key. if not found write the correct one.
//2.  objeserve what type of value returns "[myArray objectAtIndex:keyCounter]". it may not NSDictionary which may resoan of crash
```